# 3D plot of an image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, 3d

Based on the code given by Image Analyst in the answer to “3d plot of an image“ question (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/48532-3d-plot-of-an-image) I have a follow-up question:

I simplified the code and I would like to know is it possible to apply on it the jet colormap according to the gray scale intensity (Z axis) and also to fit it to the image dimensions (x,y) (e.g, in this image example the dimensions are 628x600 and therefore max x=628 and max y=600).

Thanks.

Code:

```
I = imread('E:\Temp\Canadian_maple_leaf_2.jpg'); % http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Canadian_maple_leaf_2.jpg
I=rgb2gray(I);
I = imcomplement(I);
[rows columns numberOfColorBands] = size(I);
surf(double(I));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, changing the colormap and turning the edge colours off is what you are looking for

```
surf(double(I),'EdgeColor','none');
colormap jet
```

If you want to tighten the boundaries of the plot, you can use

```
axis([0 columns 0 rows min(double(I(:))) max(double(I(:)))])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The first part works superb. The axis line shows the image in 2D point of view (top view) and indeed trim the plot to the image dimension. Is there a way to trim also the 3D figure (the surfplot)?